# Casting of template classes

Tags: c++, templates, casting

If I have a class called Wood, and a template class called 
    Chopper, and a method that accepts a reference to
    Chooper like this…

```
KeepWarm::burnFuel( Chopper <Wood>& wood_chopper );
```

How could I cast or transform Chooper , where CedarWood is derived from Wood, so that KeepWarm::burnFuel will accept it?

To recap…

```
class Wood
{
};

class CedarWood: public Wood
{
};

template class T;
class Chopper
{
  Chopper( const T value ); 
};

class KeepWarm
{
  void burnFuel( Chopper<Wood>& wood_chopper );
};

Chopper<CedarWood> some_wood;

//

KeepWarm::burnFuel( some_wood ); // the troublesome line, is this kind of thing possible?
```

Comment: You're saying `burnFuel` does not depend on the particular kind of wood, but it has such a technical dependency. The technical dependendency is a problem. Solution: remove it.

Comment: Problem is that to match my real world problem, burnFuel is unchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible, because `Chopper<Wood>` is not actually related to `Chopper<CedarWood>`.

You can solve this by making the `burnfuel` function a template function though:

```
template<typename T>
void burnfuel(Chopper<T>& chopper);
```

Comment: Well that's right, Chopper<Wood> is unrelated to Chopper<CedarWood>. Unfortunately burnFuel is not my code so I cannot  change it.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn `burnFuel` into a template:

```
class KeepWarm
{
  template<typename W>
  void burnFuel( Chopper<W>& wood_chopper );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like what you expect by using a template method with [std::is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of):

```
// code based on molbdnilo's example
template <typename W>
void burnFuel(Chopper<W>& wood_chopper) {
    if (std::is_base_of<Wood, W>::value) {
        // ok
    }
}
```

or:

```
template <typename T>
class KeepWarm
{
    template <typename W>
    void burnFuel(Chopper<W>& wood_chopper) {
        if (std::is_base_of<T, W>::value) {
            // ok
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: std::is_base_of ... now that sounds interesting. I'll investigate further. thanks.